# Table Adaptor Error when trying update

Tags: sql, vb.net, ado.net

I have a rather perplexing issue. I am using VB.net and SQL for my project.

I have a database, to which the connection works. I also have a data table and data adaptor, both of which I know work.

I am trying to update something in the database, yet it isn't working. Assume everything listed is declared correctly. What am I doing wrong?

```
teacher_control_table.Rows(0)("DATA_TeacherLockPasscode") = txtPasscode1.Text
table_adaptor2.Update(teacher_control_table)
```

That last line throws the following exception:

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled. update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception indicates there's something wrong with your UpdateCommand. 
You should set a breakpoint on `table_adaptor2.Update(teacher_control_table` and with the immidiate window or watch window inspect this value

```
table_adaptor2.Adaptor.UpdateCommand
```

Particularly the UpdateCommand's `.CommandText`, `.Connection`, and `.Parameter` Collection.

Then verify that the the command makes sense for the teacher_control_table.

Comment: Thank you! I actually chose to go a different route with the function that would have been performed with this database, but I will hold onto this solution in case run across the problem later.